# (Python) I have a string that represents an existing global variable's name, and would like to pass this to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=1

def hi(y):
    exec("global " + y) 
    exec(y + "+=1")

hi("x")
print(x)
```

I'd like the globally defined x to be incremented by 1, but the output I get is still 1. How can I correct this?

Comment: Which version of Python are you actually asking about?

Comment: What do you think `exec` does?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, find a different way ...

Comment: This looks very much like a XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access globals by a special keyword, wait for it: `globals` :)

```
def hi(var):
    globals()[var] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid exec like the plague (till you know what problems it introduces or in 5 years, which ever is later)
- single letter variable names is a no-no for future readability sake.  (it might just be for a demo but I'm saying...)
- [check out this link for scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules) (with good examples for globals in further posts)

Hope the person passing in `'x'` doesn't change it to a invalid variable name like `hi(12345)`.